What is 素か when used by itself

先輩のこと好きすぎて死にそう

The girl tells her boyfriend/senpai this after they kiss, etc
He hugs her and replies this to her:

これが素か...こっわ... (可愛すぎてびっくりした!)

What does 素 here exactly mean?

See 素 on jisho:

素【す】
Noun which may take the genitive case particle 'no'
2. plain; unadorned; undecorated; unadulterated; au naturel

素【す】 refers to a plain state of something as opposed to its decorated, modified or processed state. For example, 素のフライドポテト is a French fry without even any salt added, and 素の発言 is a straightforward statement without any joke, sarcasm or euphemism involved.
In your context, the senpai seems surprised at her attitude, thinking, "This is her/your true nature!" This implies that she usually presents a different appearance externally.
(But... did he really say this to her? While feeling a little anxious because someone is "too cute" is understandable, saying こっわ directly to someone in a romantic situation would usually cause a misunderstanding.)

So, is こっわ just 怖?  What's っ doing here?  In other words, how do you read っわ?  Contextually, it woulds seem to mean "wow" or OMG, is that correct?

@A.Ellett 怖 is the straightforward interpretation. The っ is just eye dialect for some emphasis in the delivery.

Maybe English "wo" would be better than "wow"? I'd need to see a larger passage.

@A.Ellett こっわ is 怖, but semantically it's more explicitly "this is scary" rather than "OMG". I'm not sure what's scary about the girl, though. He might have said it in a sense similar to "irresistible", but I would say saying it directly to someone can easily lead to misunderstanding.

I think it best translates to unbridled.

How do you read 素か?  スか? もとか?  Something else?

I mean, Naruto's explanation is correct, and I accept his reading. However, the correct localization is unbridled.
